# Oracle DML error logging with custom function

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, dml

When using DML Error logging in Oracle, if an invalid date format is specified in a TO_DATE function, a whole insert/select statement will fail, rather than log the date format error per bad row. I tried to get around this, by writing a custom function that catches TO_DATE errors, and raising my own error. IE:

```
create or replace FUNCTION FN_GETDATE (pDATE VARCHAR2, pFORMATSTRING VARCHAR2) RETURN DAT
IS
  pDATEEXCEPTION EXCEPTION;
  BEGIN
    RETURN TO_DATE(pDATE, pFORMATSTRING);
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'FN_GETDATE: Invalid date.');
 END;
```

This catches the exception succesfully, however the original column value passed into the pDATE parameter will not get logged in the custom errors table. How can I get a custom function to log an "original bad value" into the DML Error log table?

IE: if a column expecting a date was passed in with a value 'abc', I would like to see 'abc' in the log errors table, and not a null value.

Comment: Why can't you just append the value to the exception, e.g. `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'FN_AIS_DCC_GETDATE: Invalid date "' || pDATE || '"');`

Comment: @JeffreyKemp - that completely slipped my mind. Thanks for pointing this out. I corrected the function name in the RAISE call string. Could you update it in your comment, and also post this as answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append it to the error message, if that's what is being logged, e.g.:

```
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'FN_GETDATE: Invalid date "' || pDATE || '"');
```